# Standardization with mean/std or median/IQR?

Tags: machine-learning, standardization, z-score

I have a dataset with 10000 data points and 20 features. The features are not normally distributed (most of them have a generalized extreme value or burr distribution and all values are greater or equal to zero). Of course some classifiers requires standardized/normalized features so that the features have similar scale. Because I have some outliers in my data, I think I have to do standardization (and not normalization). Currently I'm subtracting the mean of each feature and dividing by the standard deviation. Another option would be to subtract the median and divide by the IQR.

Which of this two options is better or does it not matter?

Comment: Before scaling your data, have you attempted a transformation of your features to get them normal (I assume that would make your analysis easier) ?

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini Yes, I have tried the box-cox transformation which works well for most features but it does not work for some features (which have lot of zeroes). For those features I have just added a small constant but the transformation still does not work well.

Comment: Substracting the mean and division by standard deviation will not change the shape of the distribution and will not make it normal. If you really need to transform data to Z-scores, I would recommend to use Box-Cox wherever it is possible and just discard all features that have a lot of zeroes. You can not make them "normal", of course.

Comment: @GermanDemidov I don't want to make the features normal. Of course, Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression assumes normal distributed features (right?), so for these type of classifiers I will do BoxCox transformation. My intention with subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation is to make the features to have a similar scale, independent of the distribution. Is this not right?

Comment: Logistic regression does not assume normally-distributed features, so no need to transform for that, at least not because of the lack of normality.  Naive Bayes doesn't either, but it assumes independent features, so again, no need to transform.  (Of course if you are using a Naive Bayes calculation package, the package itself may assume Normal features, but that's not inherent in N.B. itself.)

Comment: @jbowman Alright, so if my classifier can handle non normal distributed data, I can just subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation to get similar scales for the features?

Comment: @machinery you can even do not worry about transformations. You do not need them for both of these classifiers. The phrase "similar scales" more leads to misunderstanding than really helps, for my opinion. The situation could be different if you wanted to normalise across the samples.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You could also normalize using median and IQR, which would be a more robust normalization, or median and MAD (median absolute deviation from the median) which would be more robust yet.  If you think you should resort to highly robust normalizations, though, you are, indirectly, also thinking you have some extreme data points that may well be high-leverage data points that will have a highly disproportionate effect on the estimation.  In that case, you might want to run your analysis with and without extreme observations filtered out (how to do out of this comment's scope.)

Comment: @jbowman Outlier filtering could be difficult and prone to errors I think (at what point should a data point be regarded as an outlier...). By the way, the usual way is to normalize the features (i.e. the columns) and not the data points, right?

Comment: Right.  But outliers are on a data-point basis, despite the fact that we normalize the features.   My concern is that if you think median / IQR are better location/scale estimates for normalization than mean/std dev., there's an implication that there are some extreme values that will wreck the latter.  If that is the case, then leaving them in may mess up your classifier too.  Maybe you should look at MCD / fast MCD for robust covariance estimators that can be used to help identify multivariate outliers, but in that case you'd probably want to transform to something like normality...

Comment: @jbowman MCD / fast MCD seems interesting. Do you know any Matlab (or Java) implementation of it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an R/C/C++ guy, not a Matlab / Java guy...  but I'd guess there is a Matlab implementation somewhere.